# using fgetc within a fgets?

Tags: c

im writing code in C that reads a text file then outputs a new text file but im reading my data in as a string and i then need to find a character. is there a way to do this? Within the 'buffer' i need to find the character 'R' and take the Int value after is. how will i go about doing that?? thanks this is my code so far:

```
const char ch = 'R';
char *ret;


if(strcmp(data_in,"G3")==0)
    {
        if(fgets(buffer,60,p)!= NULL)
        {


            size_t len = strlen(buffer);
            if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            {
                buffer[--len] = '\0';
            }

            ret= strchr(buffer, ch);
            fprintf(o,"CC X0.0 Y%s.0\n",ret);
            fprintf(o,"C%s DR+ R0 M\n",buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [why `while (!feof(p))` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Use `strchr()` to find a character in the string.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that's trying to find a character, unless you're talking about the check for newline at the end of the buffer. What is your specific problem?

Comment: Within the 'buffer' i need to find the character 'R' and take the Int value after is. how will i go about doing that?? thanks

Comment: Use `strchr` to find the `R`, then use `sscanf()` to read the integer after it.

Comment: Put that comment into the question, and show your code that tries to do it.

Comment: thanks ill give it a goo

Comment: tried it, it works, but it also outputs the 'R' too. is there a way to do it without outputting the 'R' too. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sscanf` to read the integer after the `R`.

```
ret = strchr(buffer, ch);
if (ret) {
    int num;
    sscanf(ret+1, "%d", &num);
    fprintf(o, "CC X0.0 Y%d.0\n", num);
}
fprintf(o, "C%s DR+ R0 M\n", buffer);
```